# JHipster with enterprise app launcher and ldap authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, jhipster

I'm currently working for an enterprise that use LDAP authentication.
They already have an Enterprise web portal that take care of the auth, and work as a launcher for the other web apps, passing them the Json Token.

I'm trying to figure how to make a JHipster monolith app working in this environment.
Since the launcher take care of the auth and user management.

I'm thinking of making a JHipster-module that would remove all the user and auth related class, but i'm beginning to doubt if this is truly the right way to do it.

If there is a better way to do this, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to generate many apps for this environment, a module is the way to go. If you plan to generate only one or few apps, then it would require less effort to skip authentication at generation time using command line options. Run `yo jhipster --help` for available options  but basically you should probably use `--auth=no --skip-user-management`

Comment: Thanks Gaël. I did try the --help option but the auth=no option wasn't present. Is there a more exhaustive list of the generator options listed somewhere ? (except looking in the source code of course)

Comment: No, and I'm not even sure for --auth=no, could be --auth-false and maybe only yo jhipster:server or jhipster:client. Usually, you can find a matching option for each json property in .yo-rc.json file